# rkhunter reports numerous warnings on haproxy open ports

Tags: haproxy

Recently I have installed **RKhunter** (v1.4.2) on a couple of loadbalancers ( **Haproxy** 2.0.14 ) running on Debian 9. Stretch. While performing a full system check I'm getting a lot or warnings about tcp ports being used by Haproxy. They look like this:

```
         Use the 'lsof -i' or 'netstat -an' command to check this.
Warning: Network TCP port 13000 is being used by /usr/sbin/haproxy. Possible rootkit: Possible Universal Rootkit (URK) SSH server
         Use the 'lsof -i' or 'netstat -an' command to check this.
Warning: Network TCP port 47018 is being used by /usr/sbin/haproxy. Possible rootkit: Possible Universal Rootkit (URK) component
         Use the 'lsof -i' or 'netstat -an' command to check this.*
```

Also, it seems that I cannot simply whitelist those ports as they seem to keep changing.
What one would do in this case ?

Comment: Maybe haproxy is opening the port at a low-level, and rkhunter is freaking at that?

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what is happening.